# Передача JSON объекта через environment в docker-compose.yml для Asp net core 2.2 приложения

Tags: asp.net-mvc, docker, docker-compose, yml

Подскажите как записать JSON объект как параметр для `yml` файла.
Вся настройка net core  приложения выполняется при запуске контейнера через `docker-compose`, путем передачи переменных окружения (`environment`).

```
services:
  webapiswc:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}webapiswc
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: WebApis/Dockerfile
    ports:
     - "44138:80"
    environment:
     - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
     - DbConnection=User ID = postgres; Password = dmitr; Server = host.docker.internal; Port = 5432; Database = OptionDevice_Prod; Integrated Security = true; Pooling = true;
     - HowCreateDb=Migrate
     - Logger_MinLevel=Information
```

Мне нужно передать вот такие настройки:

```
- Firewall= { "IPAddress": ["192.168.100.33", "192.168.100.40" ], "CIDRNotation":["110.40.88.12/28" ]}
```

Т.е. список IPAddress  и список CIDRNotation.Затем я этот объект Дессериализую.

Приняты правила, что для отладки `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Debug` настройки берутся из `appsettings.json` для  `Production` из переменных `environment`.
  Получается нужно как-то замаскировать скобки, кавычки, чтобы передалась обычная строка.
не нашел как это делается для `.yml` файлов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно обрамить всю строку в кавычки в одинарные или двойные так:

```
- 'Firewall= { "IPAddress": ["192.168.100.33", "192.168.100.40" ], "CIDRNotation":["110.40.88.12/28" ]}'
```

или так:

```
- "Firewall= { \"IPAddress\": [\"192.168.100.33\", \"192.168.100.40\" ], \"CIDRNotation\":[\"110.40.88.12/28\" ]}"
```

Во втором случае надо экранировать двойные кавычки внутри строки.

[Демо](http://nodeca.github.io/js-yaml/#yaml=ZW52aXJvbm1lbnQ6CiAgLSAnRmlyZXdhbGw9IHsgIklQQWRkcmVzcyI6IFsiMTkyLjE2OC4xMDAuMzMiLCAiMTkyLjE2OC4xMDAuNDAiIF0sICJDSURSTm90YXRpb24iOlsiMTEwLjQwLjg4LjEyLzI4IiBdfScKICAtICJGaXJld2FsbD0geyBcIklQQWRkcmVzc1wiOiBbXCIxOTIuMTY4LjEwMC4zM1wiLCBcIjE5Mi4xNjguMTAwLjQwXCIgXSwgXCJDSURSTm90YXRpb25cIjpbXCIxMTAuNDAuODguMTIvMjhcIiBdfSI=)

Comment: Спасибо, 1 вариант отлично работает.